# Does this kind of sorting has any name?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I wrote/used this kind of sorting. I'm just wondering does it has any name or is it similar to any of existing sorting algorithms. By the way, is it even efficient/worthy or not really?

```
int s = 20;

int unsorted_array[s];

//(adding numbers to unsorted_array)
//We assume that every number is different to avoid any difficulties.

int i, i2, pos;
int sorted_array[s];

//!!! sorting algo starts here:

for(i=0; i<s; i++){
   pos = 0;
   for(i2=0; i2<s; i2++){

      if(unsorted_array[i] > unsorted_array[i2]){
         pos += 1;
      }
   }

   sorted_array[pos] = unsorted_array[i];

}
```

So what do you think? is it slower/faster than other kinds of sorting methods? I'm still learning. thanks for any replies!

Comment: `int unsorted_array[s];` -- Not valid C++ due to a variable `s` being used to denote the size of the array.

Comment: `By the way, is it even efficient/worthy or not really?`  -- If you have 1,000 elements, you are looping a worse case total of 1,000,000 times.  If there were 1,000,000 elements, that makes it 1,000,000,000,000 iterations.  You be the judge if this is good or not.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie most C++ compilers will still accept this as an extension though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like some kind of reverse selection sort. A selection sort would say "what element goes in position 0?" and then find that element. Your sort seems to be saying "where does the element currently in position 0 go?", which is an equally valid question.

In terms of complexity, it's definitely `O(n^2)`, which puts it on par with the other "inefficient" schemes like insertion, selection, bubble, etc. and puts it below the more sophisticated "better" ones like merge or quick. The main concerns I have on top of that are that you're actually iterating `n^2` times, whereas algorithms like insertion or selection can get away with `n (n + 1) / 2` (triangular numbers, as opposed to square ones), which is the same complexity class but a smaller number overall. Also, your sort requires us to come up with a new array in memory, whereas a lot of the existing ones (insertion and selection, in particular, since they're sort of close to yours) can be done in constant space without allocating any more arrays.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it slower/faster than other kinds of sorting methods?

Let's analyze [the time complexity of this function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities). How much work will it need to do as the size of the unsorted list grows?

The important part are loops. They will tell us how many times you need to do the thing and that's what's important. Your loops can be broken down to this:

```
for(1 to s){
   for(1 to s){
       do that thing
   }
}
```

For each element it has to recheck every element. If there are 2 items that means you do the thing 4 times. 3 items, 9 times. 4 items, 16 times. We say the time complexity is `n^2` (`n` is the convention for the size) because as the size increases the number of steps is squared. That means the time it takes will grow exponentially as the size increases. At 10 items it takes 100 times. At 100 items it takes 10,000. At 1,000 it takes 1,000,000. `n^2` is to be avoided if possible.

[Most sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort) can do their work in `n * log(n)` or quasilinear time. As the size increases the time will grow by `n * log(n)`. This is faster than linear, but slower than exponential. `log(n)` is often the [natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm) or `ln(n)`. At 10 items it will take about 23 times. 100 about 460. At 1000 about 6900. So your algorithm is slower.

[image]

Algorithms above `n * log(n)` grow so fast it's necessary to distort the vertical time scale to meaningfully fit them on the same graph with better performing algorithms.

As you can guess, for large numbers of items it's more important to have a better performing algorithm than to do the thing faster. An `n^2` algorithm that does the thing 100 times faster than an `n log n` will lose at about 600 items.

```
n^2 = 100 n * ln(n)
n = 100 ln(n)
n / ln(n) = 100
```

Answer (score 1):

This works by finding, for each element in the array, the number of elements less than it. This is equivalent for finding its final position.

It is `O(n*n)` which is slow (there are decent `O(n*lg(n))` algorithms). But there are plenty of `O(n*n)` sorting algorithms out there so you're in good company.

It also only works with unique values which is a pretty severe limitation.

It also requires a second array to copy it to, of which most sorting algorithms don't so this is another minus point.

On the upside it does zero swaps, and only a very small number of actual copies (exactly `n` infact), which in some cases may be a good thing, but that's a pretty minor plus point.